# Distance Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

Two trains set out of two cities, A and B, simultaneously; One from A and one from B. Until the meeting one train has passed $108$ km more than the other. Later, one of the trains arrived at it's destination , in city B, $9$ hours after the meeting, while the other reached A after $16$ hours of the said meeting. Velocities of both trains were constant. What is the distance between the two cities?

I constructed a system of equations for this situation, with a final answer of $226.134$ km. 
Is this OK?

Comment: You should check your answer yourself.  Work out the velocities, and then, using the 226.134 value, figure out where the trains meet: at that point, has one train traveled 108 km more than the other? Do the times of reaching A and B yield the 9 and 16 hour values as required? Then your answer is correct.  If not, then you can conclude you've made an error, and you can work to find it.

Comment: As far as my judgment can guide me, I didn't find any, and that's why I'm posting here.

Comment: But did you do the calculations I suggested?  If you did, and everything checks out, then you can conclude you have the right answer.  This is a great skill to practice, since, I assume, you'll have to take exams, and won't be able to ask others for help during them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Train A leaves City A and travels $d_A$ km at $v_A$ km/hr to meet Train B, which left City B and traveled $d_b$ km at $v_B$ km/hr.

Since Train A arrives at its destination, it's the faster one.  So,

$$d_A = v_At_{meet}; d_B = v_Bt_{meet}; d_A = d_B + 108.$$

Following that, Trains A and B travel the remaining leg of their journeys in 9 and 16 hours, respectively:

$$\frac{d_B}{v_A} = 9; \frac{d_A}{v_B} = 16.$$

Five equations; five unknowns: $v_A, v_B, d_A, d_B, t_{meet}.$

Substitute the first two equations into the last two to get that $v_A = (4/3)v_B,$ and hence $(v_A - v_B) = (1/3)v_B.$

Combine the first three to get $(v_A - v_B)t_{meet} = 108,$ and hence $(1/3)v_Bt_{meet} = (1/3)d_B = 108.$

So $d_B = 324$ km, meaning that $d_A = 432$ km, and the sum is $756$ km.

Comment: 5 equations, really?

Comment: I got only three in total

Comment: What were the equations you got?

Comment: (X+108)/t * 9 + X + 108 = S (1)

Comment: (X/t) * 16 + X = S (2)

Comment: 2X+108 = S  (3) where S is the total distance between the two cities

Comment: I pretty sure they are alright since this is velocity double time which yields distance

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  Let me follow your equations.

Comment: Your equations should work, too.  I don't know where you went wrong.

Comment: I think I blew it a little, thanks for your help anyway...